# Common Lisp macro macroexpansion time argument typing

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

In the following function i replace the macro, with mac-1 which just returns the value of the argument it works, but mac-2 throws a type error. Can some one explain what happens and causes this error? Why is x passed to mac-2 from fun-2 is a literal symbol `x` instead of an integer?

```
(defmacro mac-1 (x) x)
(defun fun-1 (x) (mac-1 x))
(fun-1 3)               ; => 3

(defmacro mac-2 (x) (+ x 3))
(defun fun-2 (x) (mac-2 x))
(fun-2 3)
```

> Execution of a form compiled with errors.
>   Form:
>     (MAC-2 X)
>   Compile-time error:
>     during macroexpansion of (MAC-2 X). Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to intercept.
>
> The value
>      X
>    is not of type
>      NUMBER
>    when binding SB-KERNEL::X

Comment: Remember: macros work on source code, not actual runtime values. It usually makes no sense to add 3 to source code at macro expansion time.

Comment: Means `x` passed from fun-2 to mac-2 is here the source code (the data)? And the macro is expanded with this data (the symbol  `x`) as soon as fun-2 is evaluated, and the Expansion is put into the body of fun-2? Step by step I am beginning to begin to understand that I don't understand macros yet!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rename the thing:

```
(defmacro mac-2 (source-code-expression)
  (declare (type (or number list symbol string)  ; actually T,
                                                 ; since all types are allowed
                 source-code-expression))
  (+ source-code-expression 3))  ; here we have a type problem
```

This does only work for numbers. But: For example one can't add 3 to a symbol.

Remember: a macro takes arbitrary expressions and creates new ones. At macro expansion time one is supposed to see source code, not values.

> Means `x` passed from `fun-2` to `mac-2` is here the source code (the data)? And the macro is expanded with this data (the symbol `x`) as soon as `fun-2` is evaluated, and the Expansion is put into the body of `fun-2`? Step by step I am beginning to begin to understand that I don't understand macros yet!

Almost: The macro can also be expanded before the function is evaluated. For example when you compile a function, then the macros are expanded --> obviously this would not be possible, if macros would need runtime values.

Macros replaced more dynamic mechanisms exactly because they enable compilation to efficient code, where no macro expansions during runtime are needed.

The mental model of a function passing an `x` to a macro isn't really that helpful.

Think more like this as a first basic idea: a macro form will be transformed by the macro into some new expression - in a compiled implementation during compilation and in an interpreted version during evaluation.

- `mac-2` is a name for a macro
- `(mac-2 x)` is a *macro form*, since it is a compound form and `mac-2` is the name for a macro.

Generally all expressions which will be evaluated are called *form*: function form, macro form, special form, lambda form, symbol and self-evaluating objects.

> Can you explain what the type declaration in your macro is for?

Just to make clear what you can expect as an argument type.
Don't use it in code, use `check-type` instead (see below).

```
(let ((x 100))

  (mac-2 1)         ; the macro sees a number
  (mac-2 x)         ; the macro sees a symbol ! Not a number!
  (mac-2 "x")       ; the macro sees a string
  (mac-2 (+ x 20))  ; the macro sees a list !   Not a number!

  ; and so on for other data objects

 )
```

Usually in portable code when your macro expects that some argument is of a certain type or shape, then one might want to add `check-type` calls to make that clear. Let's say we want to write a macro to define a *planet* and we need a name, which should be a symbol or a string:

```
(defmacro defplanet (name coordinates)
  (check-type name (or string symbol)
              "The name of the planet must be a symbol or a string.")
  `(intern-planet ,name (check-coordinates ,coordinates)))
```

Above will check at macro expansion time the type of the value of 'name'.

Comment: Can you explain what the type declaration in your macro is for?

Answer (score 6):

`(defmacro mac-1 (x) x)` works because when  `fun-1` is defined it expands `x` to `x`. Basically it is a noop. It works for any expression since it does not do calculations at compile time.

`(defmacro mac-2 (x) (+ x 3))` will only work when the syntax `x` is a literal. eg. `(mac-2 3)` gets transformed to `6`, but in your function you give it `x`. Remember macros transform syntax so you are doing `(+ 'x 3)` (the binding `x` has the value given in `fun-2` which is the symbol `x`). The variable `x` doesn't even exist when this expansion happens so it does not even have a value.

If you expect the result of expression to become a number you can make `mac-2` do the calculations when `x` exists. Eg.

```
(defmacro mac-2 (x)
  `(+ ,x 3))
```

When`fun2` is created it will expand the macro and it will not try to do the calculations right away, but the function gets stored as:

```
(defun fun-2 (x) (+ x 3))
```

When you then call `fun-2` `x` will exist and `(+ x 3)` makes sense. Doing the `(+ x 3)` at the time you create the function does not since at that time the macro gets `x` while `x` does not yet exist.

Answer (score 4):

The key thing to understand about macros in Lisp is that they specify *source to source transformations*: a macro gets a bit of Lisp source code and returns another bit of Lisp source code, where the source code is represented (in Common Lisp & other related Lisps) as s-expressions.  And this expansion happens *before the code is evaluated* – it happens, conceptually, as part of the process of preparing the code for evaluation, often as part of the process of compiling it.

In particular, an expression like

```
(defmacro foo (x)
  ...)
```

defines a *perfecrly ordinary Lisp function* whose argument is a chunk of source code (a form) and which needs to return another chunk of source code.

When defining a macro with `defmacro` the form that the function gets is not usually visible to you, because `defmacro` picks it apart according to the arglist you give it and presents you with only the parts you care about.  But there's a special option in macro argument lists, `&whole` which lets you see, well, the whole form.

So we can define a version of your macros which display how they are called, and what the chunk of source code is:

```
(defmacro mac-1 (&whole form x)
  (format *debug-io* "~&mac-1 called with ~S~%" form)
  x)
```

This is identical to your `mac-1` but it will print, at macroexpansion time, the form it was invoked with.

And now we can define a function which uses this:

```
(defun fun-1 (x)
  (mac-1 x))
```

When the function corresponding to `mac-1` gets called, & how many times it gets called is implementation-dependent.  In a compiler-only implementation it probably gets called at least once when that form is evaluated.  In an implementation with an interpreter it may get called later.  In the implementation I'm using (LispWorks) the easy way of getting it to be called is to explicitly compile the function:

```
 > (defun fun-1 (x) (mac-1 x))
fun-1

> (compile 'fun-1)
mac-1 called with (mac-1 x)
fun-1
nil
nil
```

The first bit of output here is `mac-1` reporting its argument.  And its argument ... is the source code: it's *exactly what you can see in the function definition*.

In particular, when the macro function is called, `x` is not `3`, it's `x`: it's just a bit of source code, and the macro's job is to return another bit of source code, which in this case is just `x` again.

So now we can rewrite `mac-2` the same way and you can see why it can't possibly work:

```
(defmacro mac-2 (&whole form x)
  ;; broken
  (format *debug-io* "~&mac-2 called with ~S~%" form)
  (+ x 3))
```

And now we can try this again:

```
> (defun fun-2 (x) (mac-2 x))
fun-2

> (compile *)
mac-2 called with (mac-2 x)

Error: In + of (x 3) arguments should be of type number.
  1 (continue) Return a value to use.
  2 Supply a new first argument.
  3 (abort) Return to top loop level 0.
```

OK, so it should now be clear why `mac-2` can't work: it's called with a bit of source code (here the symbol `x`), and it's trying to add 3 to that bit of source code, which can't work unless that bit of source code happens to be the literal `3`, which it isn't in this case.  *Source code isn't numbers*.

Well, what `mac-2`'s purpose in life is is to take a bit of source code and compute another bit.  In particular it could compute a bit of source code which will add 3 to an expression when evaluated.  Here's a version which does that, while printing what it is about to return.

```
(defmacro mac-2 (&whole form x)
  (format *debug-io* "~&mac-2 called with ~S~%" form)
  (let ((result (list '+ x 3)))         ;aka `(+ ,x 3)
    (format *debug-io* "~&mac-2 -> ~S~%" result)
    result))
```

And here's a function which uses this

```
> (defun fun-3 (x) (mac-2 (sin x)))
fun-3

> (compile *)
mac-2 called with (mac-2 (sin x))
mac-2 -> (+ (sin x) 3)
fun-3
nil
nil
```

(This would be a rotten use of a macro: it's just working as a poor-person's inline function, but that's not the point here.)

---

Finally it's worth considering what something like this should do, and why:

```
(defun fun-4 (x)
  (mac-2 (mac-2 (sin x))))
```

If you can work out what will get printed when macro expansion happens *and why* you probably have a good grasp of macros in Lisp.

---

[Note to CL people: I've ignored environments above, as they don't really matter at this level!]

Comment: Interesting thing that in SBCL evaluating `(defun fun (x) (mac x))` also gives the warning __caught STYLE-WARNING: The variable X is defined but never used.__

Comment: @Student: I don't know what your definition of `mac` is, but you should not get this if it returns anything including an unquoted version of its argument.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are correct, but incomplete.

There's absolutely nothing to stop you from writing `Mac-2` as

```lisp
(defmacro Mac-2 (x)
  (if (numberp x)
      (+ x 3)
      `(+ ,x 3)))
```

Which will force the calculation to be performed at compile-time if it's a numeric argument. Usually you want this sort of thing when you have a functionality with some form of purity (say for example, `sin` on constants).

Using a macro in this way is clumsy, if you really are working with something that should be `funcall`-able, but Common-Lisp has you covered! The third way is compiler-macros.

First write your function as normal, and then use `define-compiler-macro` to write what is, essentially, a macro, but, unlike regular macros, a compiler-macro can punt and refuse to generate an expansion, in which case the function will be invoked at runtime as normal.

My utility library has some compiler macros for string building, since that's such an important part of web-programming.

1. [String concatenation](https://github.com/pjstirling/pjs-utils/blob/825d5ec5586f1eb71fbd1e32b4d988c7013762ff/strings.lisp#L3)
2. [String joining](https://github.com/pjstirling/pjs-utils/blob/825d5ec5586f1eb71fbd1e32b4d988c7013762ff/utils.lisp#L177)